# Unable to create container after installing mysql and phpmyadmin | Ubuntu

Tags: docker, mysql

I have installed docker successfully and try to install phpmyadmin and mysql.

I have did following steps.
Using below link I have pulled php version

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/codepulse/php-7.2.0-apache-mysql/
```

1. docker pull codepulse/php-7.2.0-apache-mysql
2. docker pull phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin

After installing it when I execute `docker ps -a` I could not found any container there.

Could any one help to install phpmyadmin and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling the images only make them available for you to use locally. Therefore, to use them within a container you should run the command `docker run` with the appropriate configuration for each services